# Kendo React Grid editing mode validaation

Tags: reactjs, validation, grid, kendo-grid, kendo-react-ui

I am using Kendo React Grid component in batch mode for editing inside of the grid, but I need to validate some required columns and check if they are not empty and validation is ok then enable specific button.

How can I implement validation of required columns **with showing validation message** in each column?

Comment: Any luck? I need the same.

Comment: I didn't find any solution for that @WilliamSchroederMcKinley

Comment: I'm using Formik with Yup and I was able to validate the whole table and highlight the rows with errors, but it's not ideal.